# OSRM match service for public transportation

Tags: routes, match, osrm

I'm a newbie to routing engines and my first attempts are done with OSRM. I want to use the *match* service (i.e. given a GPS dataset, I want the service to match those points to the road network in the most pausible way). Questions I have is :

1) is it possible with match service to specify public transport (e.g. subway) as the mode of transportation? I see only profiles for car, bike and foot. If not, is there a solution?

2) is it possible for match to return a multi-modal path given the timestamps of each coordinate? For example, return a sub-path that is the most plausible for pedestrian (chosen because of the low speed inferred from timestamps) followed by another subpath that is the most plausible for car (because of a higher speed)? Or is the only solution to pre-process the data to infer by myself the mode of transportation and make subsequent calls to the corresponding profile instance?